# Ember query param is null

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to get a param from the URL, but it appears it doesn't get assigned at all. I was following this guide http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/
Below is the **index.js** controller.

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({

  queryParams: ['authToken'],
  authToken: null,

  init: function() {
    var authToken = this.authToken;
    console.log(authToken);
  }
});
```

When accessing the root URL / or /#, authToken is null, which works as expected. However, when trying out /#?authToken=123, it's still null. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I couldn't get value of `authToken` inside `init` hook - I think it's called too early, but you can wrap this in `Ember.run.next` method or get its value in `setupController` hook in `IndexRoute`. This works as expected:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function (controller, model) {
    console.log(controller.get('authToken'));
  }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend ({
  queryParams: ['authToken'],
  authToken: null,
  init: function() {
    this._super();
    Ember.run.next(this, function() {
      console.log(this.get('authToken'));
    });

  }
});
```

For example, URL `site.com#/?authToken=lol` produces following console output:

```
app:49 lol
app:59 lol
```

[Working demo.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/misiquqaho#/?authToken=lol)

Comment: Indeed, by moving the code inside the next() callback, it works. However, the URL http://example.com/#/?authToken=120 is not very friendly. The docs state this URL as being accepted as well http://example.com/articles?sort=ASC. When I try to use http://example.com/?authToken=120 it doesn't work.

Comment: @Andrew Are you using Ember CLI?

Comment: Indeed I am. Would it make a difference ?

Comment: I don't think omitting `#` on JSBin is possible, but I thought it would work if you use Ember CLI.

Comment: It's ok then. I would've preferred if it also worked that way, but at least it gets the job done. Thanks !

Comment: This works if I use `?authToken=lol` but what if I want to use `/:authToken` It's returning null. But I'm able to access it in `model()` using `params.authToken` any Idea how to access in the controller?

Comment: Set it in model to property like:

`this.set('params', params);`

Then in setupController use:

`controller.set('params', this.get('params'));`

Then in controller access it using `this.get('params.authToken')`.